# What is the difference between console.writeline("hello world") and new WriteLine(){Text="Hello World"}

Tags: c#

I used to write

```
Console.WriteLine( "hello World" );
```

What is this one :

Is WriteLine is a method or a class?  ( looks like it is a class)

```
 this.Implementation = () => new Sequence
        {

            Activities = { 

              new WriteLine() {
                Text = "Hello World" }

             }
        };
```

Comment: In what scenario does this compile?

Comment: Looks like you have class `WriteLine`

Comment: second one is not compiling : [ideone](http://ideone.com/syn5ao) If you have any class named `WriteLine` then please mention else your code is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it compiles...

The first one invokes the `WriteLine` method of the `System.Console` class.  This is the normal mechanism for writing text output to the console.

The second one is using a class called `WriteLine` and assigning a value to its `Text` property.  The question is - what is this `WriteLine` class?

Assuming it's not your own invention, or part of some library you are using, perhaps it is the [`System.Activities.Statements.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.writeline.aspx) class.  You can check if you have a `using` statement at the top of your file that imports the `System.Activities.Statements` namespace.  (You would also have had to reference the `System.Activities.dll` assembly.)

By itself, this will not actually do anything.  The resulting class would have to be used in some other way to have any effect.

The `System.Activities.Statements.WriteLine` class and the assembly it belongs to are part of [Windows Workflow Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/jj684582.aspx).

See also, the answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2299104/634824), which shows an example usage of the `WriteLine` class.